# Installing Wine on Ubuntu Bionic x64

Tags: software-installation, wine, 18.04, 64-bit

I've been trying to install wine on my ubuntu 18.04 (64 bit) for an hour but couldn't succeed.

I do as all of the tutorials and instructions do it:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key
sudo apt-key add Release.key
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ xenial main'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel
```

But I always get the following results:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-devel : Depends: wine-devel (= 3.10.0~xenial)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This is the instruction in [WineHQ](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) and also there is a [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EbMIz6D1Tbo&vl=en) video doing the exact same procedure as above and succeeding, what is wrong? How can I install wine properly?

Comment: You shouldn't be using the Xenial package on Bionic.  You need to try using the Artful package of Wine's software to install the software.   This said, WineHQ does not yet have a Bionic version so you may also want to *wait* until they have one before you use their repositories, and just use the Wine version that's in the Bionic repos until then.

Comment: @ThomasWard using the main repos and installing wine-stable would result in another error ```wine32:i386 : Depends: libwine:i386 (= 3.0-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed``` and I don't know why but it removes my google-chrome-stable package

Comment: Does `apt-get install -f` help solve anything?  Don't forget you need to remove the other repos, and do `apt-get update` before it works.

Comment: I did removed the repos and also did install -f. it still isn't working

Comment: Did "I removed the repos" include uninstalling ALL packages from those repos? It's not automatic.

Comment: @user535733 yes I ```sudo apt-get remove wine*```ed it out! Then removed the repos, then tried with the original repos and then....